# How to work with event.getParam?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

Event.getParam('getString') is Returning undefined.
Event.Param('name') is returning value.
Image shown down is what returning from apex. Appended to Workspacelist

[image]``

> This is lightning Component

```
<div class="slds-m-around_xx-large">
                    <lightning:tree items="{!v.workSpaceList}"  onselect="{!c.handleUpload}"  />
                </div>
```

> This is the controller

```
handleUpload:function(component,event,helper){
    component.set("v.allFiles",false);
    component.set("v.columnIsActive",true);
    component.set("v.tileIsActive",false);
    component.set("v.disabled",false);
    var selectedvalue = event.getParam('name'); >>This returns value
       var selectedname = event.getParam('getString'); This return null.Why?
```

Can you share a note if possible what all this event.getParam return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each event has a list of parameters that are passed when an event is fired. For `onselect`, this value is `name`, and represents the unique value for the selected item. To get additional values, such as `getString`, you'd need to `find` it:

```
var allRecords = component.get("v.workSpaceList"),
    name = event.getParam("name"), 
    selected = allRecords.find(record=>record.name === name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Great job.

Answer (score 4):

To pretty print all the parameters passed to the event you may use the native JSON.stringify() method.

```
let paramStr = JSON.stringify(event.getParams(), null, 4); 
console.log(paramStr);
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-display-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

When you are not sure what parameters are included into your event, then more relevant for you is to call `getParams()`, like:

`const params = event.getParams();
console.log(params);`

That way you can list all the parameters from event.
I am making use of this approach very often during my everyday-dev-work and its very usefull. 
Feel free to ask question if any part needs more clarification.